# Programmatically change AppBar background color in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-appbarlayout

I'm pretty new to Android development and completely new to Kotlin.  I have an app with a navigation drawer, and am trying to change the color of the AppBarLayout based on what the user selects from the navigation drawer.  I've tried a few different methods, and the closest I've come has been to change the toolbar color instead of the whole AppBar.  This might be acceptable, but instead of actually setting it to the color I want, it always changes it to a dark grey.

```
when (item.itemId) {
    R.id.nav_audit -> {
        txtMain.text = "Audit"
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorAudit)
        loadAudits()
    }
    R.id.nav_testing -> {
        txtMain.text = "Testing"
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorTesting)
    }
    R.id.nav_workflow -> {
        txtMain.text = "Workflow"
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorWorkflow)
    }
    R.id.nav_other -> {
        txtMain.text = "Other"
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
    }
}
```

I've also looked at possibly changing the theme, but it looks like it may not be easy to do that after the application has already loaded.  Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Just as an update, I came across this article that isn't exactly what I was trying to do, and is way more complicated than I was hoping to make this, but the result looks amazing.  If I can wrap my head around all of this, It may prove to be my answer, but I am still hoping to find a simpler solution.

[link](https://androiduipatterns.com/toolbar-delight-8c5e4500b899)

Comment: Another option, which may be much simpler, would be to open a new activity each time a selection is made from the menu.  This way, each activity could have it's own AppBar with it's own unique color.  The downside to this is that the navigation drawer would need to be duplicated for each activity,

Answer (score 2):

Besides changing the color of the Toolbar that you are already doing, one way to change the status bar in Kotlin is like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   (activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.window?.statusBarColor = 
        ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color. colorTesting)
 }
```

You could do a method that returns the color depending on itemId

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've long since moved on from this project, though I never got that part of it working quite how I wanted.  I currently don't have an Android development environment set up, but I'll try this out when I get a chance.